# Remove all associations with Brackets

Tags: finder, filesystem

I just downloaded Brackets (web development IDE) and it associated lots of unnecessary file formats like .json that I would normally open using Sublime. Is there any way I can remove all file associations with Brackets and assign them to Sublime or at least, to TextEdit?

Answer (score 2):

**Here's how to do it with any file (first method):**

1. Highlight and right-click the file you want to change the default app for
2. Mouse over `Open with...` then click `Other`[image]
3. Choose the desired application (i.e. Sublime) in the `Choose Application` prompt
4. Tick the checkbox `Always Open With`, then press `Open` (then close the application)

**Alternatively:**

1. Highlight and right-click the file you want to change the default app for
2. Select `Get Info`
3. Select `Open with...` in the window that just opened
4. Choose the desired application (from the drop-down list or `Other`)

   1. If you are using `Other`, make sure to check `Always Open With` before pressing `Add`.
5. Ensure that the default application is displayed in the small box (as seen below, with Archive Utility)[image]
6. Select `Change All...` to apply it to all files of the same type.

Comment: Looks great, but not entirely what I was looking for. Due to very poor design of Brackets, I don't even know what file types they associated with their app and I was wondering if there is an option to remove all associations with certain app like you can on Windows. It's not a deal breaker, but, it's really frustrating when every single file opens in an app that is meant to be used for web development, not for file editing. Thanks anyways :)